# excel VBA Range for columns using count

Tags: excel, vba

In my code I have the following statement that works just the way I want it. The question is how would I rewrite this to work for columns?

```
lastRow = Sheets(sName).Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
```

so far I have...

```
partNumber = Sheets("RM_RESULTS").Range(Columns.count & 1).End(xlLeft).Column
```

It's obviously something so simple but everything I try...no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
partnumber = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Set `Cells(1` as needed with your cellnumber